# Shopify GraphQL list all unique product options

Tags: graphql, shopify-api

I need to list all unique product-options within a Shopify store using the GraphQL API. However, I'm unable to do so and can't find the solution in the API docs.

Currently, I can query all product-options in the store using GraphQL-query:

```
query {
    translatableResources(first:250, resourceType:PRODUCT_OPTION) {
        nodes {
            resourceId,
            translatableContent {
                key,
                locale,
                type,
                value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns me a list with the product-options. However, the options are returned for each product, therefore this list can be very long when the store has many products. For example, I get the product-option 'Kleur' meaning Color multiple times, as multiple products have this option:

```
[resourceId] => gid://shopify/ProductOption/10539451875649
[translatableContent] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => name
                [locale] => nl
                [type] => SINGLE_LINE_TEXT_FIELD
                [value] => Kleur
            )

    )
[resourceId] => gid://shopify/ProductOption/10543580086593
[translatableContent] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => name
                [locale] => nl
                [type] => SINGLE_LINE_TEXT_FIELD
                [value] => Kleur
            )

    )
```

As you can see, the same value 'Kleur' is returned for two different product option id's. As said, I want to prevent a huge list which requires pagination to be processed depending on the number of products (with these product-options enabled).

Therefore, I'm looking for a GraphQL-query that returns me the ***unique*** product-option values, but I can't find it anywhere in the docs.